# Open internal PhoneGap page from external page in view (using native android menu)

Tags: android, cordova

In my phonegap project I created native android menu according to [this tutorial](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2012/11/building-native-menu-with-phonegap.html). Required page (such as settings.html) is displayed with calling view javascript (`this.appView.sendJavascript`).

How to **display internal phonegap page (such as settings.html) when in view is external page (displayed with `window.location=EXTERNAL_URL`)**.

Use case:

User scanned bar code with my phonegap application. Then he is redirected to external pages (with `window.location`) and he can browse there. Then he want go back to phonegap application (to scan another bar code or change settings etc.). And here is the problem - I don't know how to open specific phonegap page from external page in view because I can't call my JS scripts.

Comment: Is there some possiblity **open phonegap page form Android Activity method for menu**?

Answer (score 0):

I used `this.appView.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/settings.html)`

I think that it's not the best way but I didn't invent better solution and this one works.